# Why does my Angular Bootstrap modal not consistently close when clicking save using Cypress?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cypress

I am using a bootstrap modal in Angular. When cypress clicks on the save button on the modal sometimes it will close and sometimes it won’t.

### cypress code

```
      it('Example test', () => {
        cy.get('[data-cy="open-modal"]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy="input"]').select('Active')
        cy.get('[data-cy="btn"]').click()
        cy.get('[data-cy="modal"]').should('not.be.visible')
      })
```

### HTML

```
<button data-cy="open-modal" (click)="showModal()">Open Modal</button>

<div id="test-modal" class="modal custom-modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content" data-cy="modal">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Example Modal</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label>Test modal</label>
            <select class="form-control select" value="" type="text" formControlName="angular-form" data-cy="input">
              <option>Active</option>
              <option>Inactive</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="submit-section">
            <button class="btn btn-primary submit-btn"
              [disabled]="!editWeeklyRuleStatusForm.valid" data-cy="btn">Save</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### Typescript

```
  showModal(): void {
    $('#test-modal').modal('show')
  }

  submitForm(): void {
    $('#test-modal').modal('hide');
  }
```

I have tried using `cy.wait()` to wait for the modal to close. I have also tried to assert that the modal should not be visible. This assertion will pass even though the modal is still visible and will fail later in the test after waiting. Either way the modal is not being consistently closed by clicking on the save button.